# Typescript property type lookup doesn't work with optional key

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with optional parameter, and I want the return type to be based on whether the user passes this key:

```
interface Base {
  id: string;
  optional?: string;
}

declare function test<T extends Base>(value: T): T['optional'] extends undefined ? number : string;

test({ id: '3' })
```

But in the above example, the return type is `string`. Is there any way to make it work?

```
 test({ id: '3' }) => return type should be number
 test({ id: '3', optional: '' }) => return type should be string
```

Comment: Why not just use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that an optional property `optional?: string` can actually be three different types once it's matched to the generic parameter.

- `string` as in `{ optional: 'foo' }`
- `undefined` as in `{ optional: undefined }`
- `never` as in `{}`

So in `test({ id: '3' })` `T['optional']` is `never`, and `T['optional'] extends undefined` is falsy.

It's probably simplest to check for the positive case `string` instead:

```
T['optional'] extends string ? string : number;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+yA9gA5jCMhwA2A-GRVRB1cAX1y4iEBFzhQUMAK4gEbDskgUAPABVkEAB6QQRDGkwQAfAAoAbtwUQy2gJROA2gHIWqzlw8BdPUMIY1MBGmQeckoIshAFAFsAI2h6XAQOCmQ4OMSUqGQAXnUICitsQlJkDwBmD2QRZ2QAemaii2Q5MAUoEHUAT2YUDAALRgUuImQU5Hjk6HTMsGn+GKEikrKK4jJajwAaJlZ2X136xpa2wo6unr6wQeGxiamZ8KFcIA)

---

However, you can avoid generic altogether with a simple [overload.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
declare function test(value: Base & { optional: string }): string;
declare function test(value: Base): number;
```

The first signature accepts a `Base & { optional: string }` which would not match the case where `optional` is omitted. The second signature catches any other valid `Base`, which would be the undefined or missing case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+yA9gA5jCMhwA2A-GRVRB1cAX1y4iEBFzhQUMAK4gEbDskgUAFADduCiGXRZkAMmTYmrdpy79KNZCICUdwcMnTZ8pSuvqIWrpc+oaYEC7IIAoAtgBG0PS4CBwUyHBkUXHQyAC8-loWxGQA5ADMxY5OyAD01bkAfMhyYApQIOoAnswoGAAWjApcRMjxkTHxUEkpYCOuDnkaYJqFpMhlxQA0lqo2JRXONXU5jc2t7WBdPf2Dw6MCNLhAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So why T['optional'] extends never doesn't work?

Comment: That's a good question! I'm not sure. Maybe it's not `never`, but I can't seem to figure out what at actually _is_ in there either.